# Why is Elijah/Elias mentioned Luke 9:54 in the KJV but not in some other bible versions such as the NASB?

Tags: luke, textual-criticism

> Luke 9:54 KJV:
> And when his disciples James and John saw this, they said, Lord, wilt thou that we command fire to come down from heaven, and consume them, **even as Elias did**?

> Luke 9:54 NASB:
> When His disciples James and John saw this, they said, “Lord, do You want us to command fire to come down from heaven and consume them?”

Why is Elijah mentioned Luke 9:54 in the KJV but not in some other bible versions such as the NASB?

Comment: @NigelJ Thank you for the reply and the link.

Comment: This recent [related question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/49151/why-is-the-phrase-not-being-myself-under-the-law-missing-in-1-corinthians-920) has answers which may answer your own question

Comment: The words ως και ηλιας εποιησεν (even as Elias did) are present in the _Textus Receptus_ but not in the Westcott & Hort/Nestle Aland text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I offer this answer only for completeness.  I think this and related questions should be referred to UBS5 and NA28 to see what MSS support each text type.

UBS5 regards the omission of the phrase ὡς καὶ Ἠλίας ἐποίησε (= even as Elijah did) as {B} - not certain but somewhat confident.

For a complete list of MSS of that support the Textus Receptus vs Byzantine text vs the UBS5 selected text, see UBS5 for a very long list of documents.

Comment: Thank you. Would you know of an online link I could use to see the list of sources from where the texts comes and where they differ?

Comment: @Glenn - Unfortunately, I do not know of an on-line source.  I have about 20 versions of the GNT but all in paper.  The best for MSS references is the UBS5

Comment: no problem thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies I should have done some more research before asking the question. It seems that it is because the KJV is translated from the Textus Receptus, which contains the phrase. While the NASB and some other versions aren't.

As a side note neither the Codex Vaticanus or the Codex Sinaiticus mention Elijah in that verse, and both seem to have a large chunk of verses 9:55-56 missing (as do some other texts mentioned in their wikipedia pages).

Comment: Quite right.  All such questions about textual criticism should first consult UBS5 & NA28 which list the sources from the text comes and where they differ.